# Telnet HTTP free server restriction

Tags: http, request, telnet

I'd like to get the whole page using telnet:

telnet
o test.bugs3.com 80
GET / HTTP/1.0

Actually I can get almost any website but this one. The same problem occurs with other free servers. I just want to know what exactly causes some restriction like that.
The request is as following:

```
Connected.
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server:
Date: Mon, 11 Nov 2013 04:11:47 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 328
Last-Modified: Thu, 16 May 2013 12:17:53 GMT
Connection: close
Accept-Ranges: bytes

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>Account unavailable</title>
</head><body>

<h1>Account unavailable</h1>

<p>Maybe account have been moved, deleted, suspended or not activated yet.

<p>The requested resource could not be found but may be available again in
the future.

<hr>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you aren't sending a `Host: test.bugs3.com\r\n` header. [RFC 2616 #14.23](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt): "A client MUST include a Host header field in all HTTP/1.1 request messages."

Comment: So one website requires HTTP version 1.1 with Host and Connection headers, and another one is ok with the version 1.0 without them. Am I right?

Comment: HTTP 1.1 requires it. HTTP 1.0 appears not to. If you have really encountered an HTTP 1.0 server that would explain it.